# linq to xml getting value of an attribute out of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

Hello I got the following problem. I want to get the value of the **baseLocation(D:\NewSites\TEST**) out of the following code using `linq`.
I tried a few things but it doesn`t seem to work.
Any ideas how this would be done?
Thanks in advance.
Trustos

I started with something like this but this returned null

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("C:\\web.config");
var dataList = from item in document.Descendants("configuration") select item;
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
    </log4net>
    <web>
        <website runtimeMode="Development" siteName="TEST" baseLocation="D:\NewSites\TEST"      sitePath="D:\NewSites\TEST\WebApps\Website" siteUri="http://test.co.uk" s    iteEmail="test@gmail.com" />
        <cms defaultTemplate="TEST\Content.aspx" templatesUrl="/Manager/Templates/">
        <publishingLocations>
            <publishingLocation name="TEST" uri="http://test.co.uk" path="WebApps\Website" />
        </publishingLocations>
        <redirectables />
        <searchEngineSiteMapNotifications />
        <siteMapXmlUrls />
        <pingServices />
        <reservedTemplates />
        <templateFilters />
        </cms>
    </web>
    <location path="Manager">
    </location>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How are LINQ to SQL and XML supposed to come together? Please show your approaches, so we can fix them for you.

Comment: Yeah I m sorry it is XML big type mistake there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use LINQ and C# to pull an attribute, use something like this

```
XDocument document = Xdocument.Load("~/web.config");
var location = document.Descendants().Single(i=>i.Attribute("baseLocation") !=null)
               .Attribute("baseLocation").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This will do the task:

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"location of xml/config");//  xml.Load(@""~/web.config");
XmlNode node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//website");
Response.Write(node.Attributes["baseLocation"].Value);
```

Let me know if you need further assistance, or if it helped please mark.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
string baseLocation = document.Descendants("website").First().Attribute("baseLocation").Value;
```